# HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100) apache + passanger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, phusion

I am using ruby on rails with phusion passenger with apache and I am
getting below error. Sometime my server is hangged and ssh login
not working. I have to reboot instance then it will work.

```
[Client 2-10588] Returning HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100)
```

Comment: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1424

Answer (score 2):

Increase the max request queue size:

```
passenger_max_request_queue_size 200;
```

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_max_request_queue_size

Comment: Please tell me file name where i should put this kine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apache but should be in your passenger configuration: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/, probably in your Passengerfile.json (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html), as per the Apache/Passenger intro doc: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/intro.html . Hope this helps!

Comment: where i will make this changes. I have nginx and passenger on my machine

Comment: PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize this what should go in the apache configuration file